# Converting text data into time in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a coloumn in excel wherein time has been entered as text i.e.,2:50AM . Now I would like to convert that into time format. Kindly advice how I can achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the column you want to change the format...

Press CTRL + 1 on keyboeard,

A dialogue box will popup.

[image]

Click on Time and change the format

Comment: Thanks Stephen.However,it doesn't work when I try to find the difference between times in two coloumn. I have the values in coloumn B and C which are in text format. B2 has the value 12:50 AM and C2 has the value 12:53 AM . I tried to convert them into Time format by following the steps mentioned by you. However,while calculating the difference it doesn't give the result. Any suggestion?

Comment: visit this link http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/calculate-the-difference-between-two-times-HP003056108.aspx